# Update records in firebase using php by UUID

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, php-7.2

I am new to firebase and I want to update single record by UUID using PHP , I have checked and tried many solutions available on google but didn't find any solution which fullfill my requirement, screenshot attached of my collection where i want to update `-LRphnkdvcEN5cIKkbDs` UUID's data. Below is my code

[image]

**UPDATE CODE**

```
public function update(array $data){
    if(empty($data) || !isset($data)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    else{
        $reference = $this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->orderByChild('id')->equalTo($data['record_id'])->update($data);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the key of the node you want to update, you don't need a query. You can just construct the path to the node, and call `update` on that:

```
$reference = $this->database->getReference($this->dbname."/".$data['record_id'])->update($data);
```

Or

```
$reference = $this->database->getReference($this->dbname).getChild($data['record_id'])->update($data);
```

Comment: I want to know is there any way by which I can set datatype for fields in firebase, and is it possible to create multiple tables(collections) in firebase for creating a web portal as well as android and ios app ?

Comment: I have an issue regarding child function in firebase